# Check which image view was pressed using UITapGestureRecognizer in Swift

Tags: swift, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have three `UITapGestureRecognizers`.
They look like that:

```
gestureImageViewUp = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.checkChoice(_:)))
self.imageViewUp.addGestureRecognizer(gestureImageViewUp)

gestureImageViewDown = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.checkChoice(_:)))
self.imageViewDown.addGestureRecognizer(gestureImageViewDown)

gestureImageViewMiddle = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.checkChoice(_:)))
self.imageViewMiddle.addGestureRecognizer(gestureImageViewMiddle)
```

I want to check which of them was pressed. How can I solve that?

Comment: You can have 3 different function calls on the selector, or you can pass a parameter on checkChoice Method to identify which one was pressed.

Comment: Can you please provide some working code?

Comment: Just try calling 3 different  methods if you don't want how to send parameters via your function, would be the fastest test.

Comment: just add different tags to your views and check the `gesture.view.tag value`. BTW you just need 1 tapGestureRecognizer object. Add the same one to all your views

Comment: Thanks for the hint with the `tag`! Adding 1 gesture recognizer to all views doesn't work in swift but thank you anyway!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't need more then one recogniser, just attach it to the view and in the selector check which imageview was clicked.

```
func onPress(_ guesture: UIGestureRecognizer) {

    guard let location = guesture.location(in: self.view)  else { return }

    if gestureImageViewUp.frame.contains(location) {
        // …
    }
    if gestureImageViewDown.frame.contains(location) {
        // …
    }
    if gestureImageViewMiddle.frame.contains(location) {
        // …
    }
}
```

Not tested sorry, it would be easier if you pasted code instead of snapshots